# Highest value of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array, which contains several numbers, like this:

```
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

I would like to get smallest and greatest number from this array. It seems pretty easy task, but accidently I get wrong output for code below.

```
function highAndLow(numbers){
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
var m = 0, i = 0, n = args.length;

console.log(args.length)

    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        if (args[i] > m) {
            m = args[i];
            console.log(m)
        }
    }

return m

}
```

It says length is 1 and return value is 0.

Comment: That's not an array, it's a string.

Comment: make the second line `var arguments = numbers.split(' ');`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a string as parameter. You need to split first. And convert to Number.

```
args = numbers.split(' ').map(Number);
```

A minor hint: You can use the first element as first min/max value and iterate from the second element.

```js
function highAndLow(numbers) {
    var args = numbers.split(' ').map(Number),
        min = args[0],
        max = args[0],
        i,
        n = args.length;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (args[i] < min) {
            min = args[i];
        }
        if (args[i] > max) {
            max = args[i];
        }
    }
    return { min: min, max: max };
}

console.log(highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"));
```

Comment: `Math.max.apply(Math,numbers.split(' ').map(Number));`

Comment: right, but its the splitting problem, not the max problem.

Comment: Just a curious question, `Math.max` or `Math.min` would run loop internally. So if we run single loop and assign both `min` and `max` value, it should be faster. Also `.apply` will update context, so it should take few ms more. But `.apply` is running faster. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4a5hpby/). How?

Comment: @NinaScholz : yup I know...... I just added because it may helpful for the user :)

Comment: @Rajesh I think you should change it to `str.split(/\s+/);` to gain accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Math.max(), Math.min()`:

```js
function highAndLow(str){
  var arr = str.split(/\s/);
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
  var min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);
  console.log('Max:::', max, " Min::::", min);
}

highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string as parameter to your function.

```
highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

should be replace with

```
highAndLow([4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6]);
```

to actually pass an array with numbers.

Comment: Also, try to not do a `str.split(' ')` in the function itself. Try to pass the value as an actual array (aka, do the work outside the function). So, if you don't have control over the string part (maybe a weird api), do something like `highAndLow(inputStr.split(' '))`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function highAndLow(data) {
  var data = "4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6";
  var dataArr = data.split(' ').map(Number);
  var result = {};
  result.max = Math.max.apply(Math, dataArr);
  result.min = Math.min.apply(Math, dataArr);
  return result;
}
var res = highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
console.log(res.min);
console.log(res.max);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest way of doing it:

```js
function highAndLow(str) {
  str = str.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt(a) - parseInt(b)
  });
  return [str[str.length - 1],
    str[0]
  ];
}
document.write(highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6'));
```

Comment: I like the `sort`, is this more/less/as performant vs `min`/`max`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by `min`/`max`, but it has pretty performance. Could be better, for instance by calling `parseInt` in a `.map` call and then sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function highAndLow(numbers) 
 {

                var args = numbers.split(" ");                    
                console.log(args.length)
                var min = Math.min.apply(Math, args),
                max = Math.max.apply(Math, args);
                console.log(min);
                console.log(max);


 }

 highAndLow('4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6');
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The splice.call is returning some thing else not the length of array because it is seeing everything as characters.

This implementation should help out ,

1. split the string with space using array.split(delimter) [Javascript Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
2. Then convert the splitted array to number as you do the test
3. We loop through and test for minimum and maximum array value

```js
// Code goes here

 
function highAndLow(numbers){
  var args = numbers.split(" ");
  
  var n= args.length;
  
  document.getElementById("argLength").innerHTML="Array Length:"+n;
  
  var i=0;
  var max = Number(args[i]);
  var min = Number(args[i]);
  
  for(i=1;i<n; i++){
    var num=Number(args[i]);
    
    if(num>max)
        max=num;
  
    if(min>num)   
      min=num;
    
  }
  
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=("Min:"+min+", Max:"+max);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 
  </head>

  <body onload='highAndLow("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6");'>
    
    <h1 id="argLength"></h1>
    
    <h1 id="output"> </h1>
  </body>

</html>
```